# Queuing an ADO build using URL parameters

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

In Jenkins you can create a URL that takes you to the "Build with parameters" page and pre populates the parameters you pass on the URL. Then, the user can press the "Run" button.

[https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build#:~:text=http%3A//server/job/myjob/buildWithParameters%3FPARAMETER%3DValue](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build#:%7E:text=http%3A//server/job/myjob/buildWithParameters%3FPARAMETER%3DValue)

Is there such a feature in Azure ADO? Ideally I'd like to build a URL (https://dev.azure.com/org/_build?definitionId=12345&VAR1=FOO&VAR2=BAR) where I can prepopulate some variables and land on the ADO page with the "Run Pipeline" pop-up open and filled with the URL variables and ready for the user to press "Run".

The closest I was able to find is queuing a build from the REST API, but for my use case I'd love to have the user land on a page and manually run the pipeline with the pre-populated fields from the URL.

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1#uri-parameters:~:text=Definitions-,Queues%20a%20build,-HTTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1#uri-parameters:%7E:text=Definitions-,Queues%20a%20build,-HTTP)

Answer (score 0):

No, Azure Pipelines do not support such feature currently.

For parameters in Azure Pipelines, you can set the values by the following ways:

- In the YAML file where define the parameter, you can set the default value of the parameter.
- In the YAML file, you also can set a list of available values of the parameter.
- When manually the pipeline, on the pop-up **Run pipeline** window, you can specify a new value to overwrite the default value or select a value from the listed available values.

After specifying/selecting a new value of the parameter on the **Run pipeline** window, if you close the window without starting the run, then every time when you reopen the window, the value you specify/select previously will not persist.

---

If your projects really need Azure Pipelines have the similar feature as that on Jenkins, I recommend you try to report a feature request on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest). This could make it more convenient for the engineer teams to receive and understand your ideas. And your feedback also could be helpful for improving the Azure DevOps products.

---